# Heap insert, delete k elements

Tags: algorithm, heap

I have the following problem (I think it's well known/standard) that I am thinking at:

Verify that listing k smallest elements in a binary min-heap is O(k).

I was thinking at traversing the big min-heap in [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), maintaining a min-heap instead of a simple queue. Initially, the auxiliary min-heap contains the root of my big min-heap. At each step I extract the minimum and I add all its children (maximum 2). The algorithm stops after k extract-mins on the auxiliary min-heap. The size of the auxiliary min-heap is O(k) (for-each min-key extracted I insert its children, maximum 2).

The problem is that extract-min has O(log k) complexity, thus this algorithm has O(k log k) complexity. And I have to find one in O(k).

Do you have any ideas/papers I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right that 'delete k elements' might not be relevant. I'm not confusing the heap size with the number of smallest elements to extract. I need only to access these k elements, not to remove from the heap. L.E. did you remove your comment?

Comment: yes, I deleted my comment since I realized **I** was confusing things :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. At each step, instead of executing extract-min I execute increase-key. I searched for a data structure that has O(1) worst-case time for increase-key, insert-key and get-min, and I found the *[Brodal queue](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.8133)*.

For more information you may look at the [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap), because the Brodal queue is based on concepts developed by the Fibonacci heap.

So, at each step I have the following sequence of operations:

1. min = get-min(Auxiliary Heap)
2. let (v1, v2) be the children of min
3. increase-min(Auxiliary Heap, root, v1)
4. insert(Auxiliary heap, v2)

Each of these 4 operations have O(1) worst-case complexity.

Comment: Brodal min-queues have O(1) decrease-key, not O(1) increase-key.

Comment: There cannot be O(1) insert, find-min, and decrease-min, as that would allow O(n) sorting: note that increasing the minimum to infinity is as good as deleting it.

Comment: Er... I meant there cannot be O(1) insert, find-min, and *increase*-key.

Answer (score 2):

Googling for 'heap selection algorithm', I came across 'Frederickson's heap selection algorithm' which leads to [this paper](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/research/technical_reports/1991/TR%2091-027.pdf) (27 pages...).

Comment: Well, the indicated algorithm has O(k) complexity for selecting kth element. If I want to select k elements then the cost will be sum of i, with i from 1 to k which is O(k*k).

Comment: Once you have the kth smallest element (let's call it x), do a depth first walk of the heap. For each node whose value is <= x, visit both children. Now there are k nodes whose value is <= x (by construction of x) in the worst case, you'll visit both children of each of these nodes even if they're > x. So in the worst case, you'll visit (1 parent + 2 children) * k = 3 * k nodes in the heap (see e.g. 'The Algorithm Design Manual' by S. Skiena, section 4.3.4). I.e. once you know the kth smallest element, finding the smaller k-1 elements can be done in O(k) time.